# When do we need to send data to server?

Tags: javascript, html, server

Currently, I want to display students' information in a web page. When this web page is loaded, a server sends all students'(maybe 1000+) information to a js file which is used to display information in that web page. After a user selecting some filter options (for example, student's course or country),is it a good idea to send these filter options to the server and send back some information about which students' information should be displayed? Actually, the refinement can be done within the js file without sending data to server. So I just feel that it is pointless to send filter options to the server. So when do we need to send data to server in my case? Should I send all students' information when loading the web page?

Comment: Why is there a js file involved? why not just re-query the database based on the filter values in real time and send the matching records back?

Comment: I agree with Alex K. Utilizing multiple queries for filtering purposes is the way to go.

Comment: But in client side, it should have a place to store students' information otherwise how to display data?

Comment: Are you now asking how to display retrieved data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody will read 1000+ students' entries at once, it might be a good idea to fetch only as much results as you initially need to display.

For example if you use result pagination and the default is displaying 50 results per page, fetch only the first 50 results. If a filter is cast, query your server again with these filtering rules and display the relevant results.

However, if you must use the 1000+ results at once, then I see no need in querying the server. It's basically useless as you already have all the data in the client side. Just filter it locally.

Again, I highly recommend changing your approach to fetch only what you need to display each time.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this link it's a similar kind of question.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215998/display-large-amount-of-data-to-client-through-pagination

Comment: Thanks, I will have  a look.